# OneLogin SSO - Multiple ACS (Consumer) URL on single SAML Application

Tags: single-sign-on, onelogin

I'm using OneLogin for Single Sign On on my application. I'd like to have a different URL to authenticate users of the mobile app (infrastructure reasons). On the OneLogin app admin page it seems I can only define one ACS (Consumer) URL, whereas on IDP's like Azure I can have multiple. Is this possible on OneLogin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that OneLogin does not have this feature at the moment. I'm implementing a server cluster that would utilize a single multi-san certificate and we were hoping to be able to create a single connector with OneLogin but they say that they can't provide this at the moment and the best they can do is put in a feature request to their development team.

Regards,

Hunor

Comment: Confirmed this myself with OneLogin support staff.

Answer (score 0):

Looking today I can see that there are some application configurations that support multiple ACS URLs:

[image: Searching for applications with Multi ACS in title]

If you configure a new application with one of them it is possible to list multiple ACS URLs (although I can't see a way to specify the ACS Index for each of them):

[image: Multiple ACS URLs in OneLogin application configuration]

I'm not sure if it's possible to repurpose one of those configurations for a completely different service but at this stage I think it would be the only possible way as I can't find a generic Multi ACS configuration.